# ファイルのアップロード(scp)と、実行(ssh)を一回の接続で行いたい

Tags: linux

手元のマシンからリモートにプログラムをアップロードして、実行するシェルを作成しました。

```sh
#/bin/sh
scp prgoram 192.168.0.1:~ 
ssh 192.168.0.1 "./program"
```

しかし、これだとリモートサーバに二回接続するため、認証鍵のパスフレーズを二回入力しなくてはいけません。

これは手間なので、一回にしたいです。
なにか方法はないでしょうか。

なお、ControlPersist で一定時間接続を維持しておくのは避けたいです。
https://rcmdnk.com/blog/2015/05/13/computer-remote/

Comment: 目的は `ssh` することそのものではなく、送ったプログラムを実行すること、でしょうか？

Comment: @PicoSushi  はい、そうです。

Comment: `ControlPersist` は避けたいとのことですが、 `ControlMaster` のみ使うことは可能でしょうか？ / [同様の質問](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57807/copy-over-ssh-and-execute-commands-in-one-session)では、 `ControlMaster` を使って1つの接続を使い回す例が最も票を集めているようです。

Comment: @PicoSushi いいえ、それも避けたいです。使う人に設定をしてもらうのは手間がかかるため、シェルだけで完結させたいです。

Comment: まぁ、`cat program | ssh 192.168.0.1 'cat > program && chmod 0755 program && ./program'` などとすれば実行できます。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます、できました！ こちらを回答に記載していただいてもよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 回答として記載しましたが、より適切な方法があるかもしれません。一つの方法としてご理解下さい。

Comment: @metropolis はい、理解しております。より適切な方法があれば投票により上位に来ますので、現時点でご回答いただいた内容で構いません。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

そのプログラムファイルを cat + ssh コマンドでリモート側へコピーする方法が考えられます。

```sh
$ cat program | ssh 192.168.0.1 'cat > program && chmod 0755 program && ./program'
```

Comment: `ssh -e none` てオプションを付けないと cat してるデータが化けて保存されてしまいますよ。改行+`~`がエスケープシーケンスとして解釈されて。

Comment: @criticabug ええと、どういう意味でしょうか？ ssh の `-e` オプションの説明では `Sets the escape character for sessions with a pty` と記載されていますが、上記のコマンドでは `pty(pseudo tty)` は使っていませんが。

Comment: すみません、確かにこれならバイナリ透過ですね… もし program が端末からの入力を必要とする場合には `-t` とか `-e none` とか要るかもしれません。自分でもこう対処した記憶があり、他にもそう言ってる人はいるものの http://matt.might.net/articles/ssh-hacks/ リダイレクトで保存してるだけなら不要です。

Answer (score 2):

ssh-agent を使うと入力は1回で済みます。

```
#!/bin/sh
KEY=path/to/keyfile       # 秘密鍵
eval `ssh-agent`          # ssh-agent を起動。
ssh-add $KEY              # 秘密鍵をメモリ上に読み込む
scp prgoram 192.168.0.1:~ 
ssh 192.168.0.1 "./program" 
kill $SSH_AGENT_PID       # SSHエージェントを終了。
```

もしくは expect で自動化する方法でも実現出来ると思います。